# How to discover torch model name from the model itself?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I am creating a built in torch model in this way:

```
m = torchvision.models.resnet50()
```

and I want to discover the model's name (resnet50 in this case) using the variable m afterwards.
When calling `type(m)` I get `torchvision.models.resnet.ResNet` which is almost the answer but the depth is important to me as well. I could try to iterate `m.modules` (which is 151 modules long in this way) and infer the resblocks depth but that would work entirely different in other models (like inception, alexnet and so on).

Comment: the answer `ResNet` is not enough you want "50" as well?

Comment: @Shai yes exactly

Comment: since the only difference between the different `ResNet` models is in their `layers` configuration, your solution most likely will be tailored specifically to `ResNet`.

Comment: @Shai that's right. So this is why I'm asking for a more generic way to do that, so if I later change my model to another kind of model, I would get the full name without further layers calculations

Comment: You can write wrapper model over this and add name attribute?

Comment: @UmangGupta True I thought of that solution but I think torch might already have a similar solution. Do you think that's not the case?

Comment: I don't think torch has anything like that... see https://github.com/pytorch/vision/tree/master/torchvision/models

Answer (score 0):

ResNet50 is the name of a function if we look at the code [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/resnet.py).

So the only way is the one suggested by Umang Gupta above : write a Wrapper model

```py
model = torchvision.models.resnet50()
model.name = 'Resnet-50'
```